# In Android MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT not working in 6.0 and uper version device

Tags: android, video, video-capture, android-video-player

I'm using LG Nexus(6.0). When I have use the camera to capture video using below code.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
   fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
    // set video quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
```

I have given its duration limit using below code.

```
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30);
```

The camera seems to ignore the duration limit. On any 6.0 device, it does not work. Is there an another way to limit the capture video duration on 6.0 + devices?

Comment: I also verified this issue exists only for Google Camera App whose Version is greater than "2.5.052(2005148-30)".

Currently, on Play store, Google Camera App version is "3.2.045(2821762-30)" by using this version you can easily reproduce this issue. Previously Google Camera EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT was working on the V2.5.052.

Comment: any solutions ?

Answer (score 6):

> The camera seems to ignore the duration limit. On any 6.0 device it does not work.

There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models from hundreds of manufacturers. Those devices will have hundreds of different pre-installed camera apps, plus possibly camera apps installed by users. Any of them can be what responds to an `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` request, and any of them can have bugs. This issue is not tied to an Android OS version.

> Is there a other way to limit the capture video duration on 6.0 + devices?

Not with `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`. You are delegating the work to a third-party app, and that app can do whatever it wants.

If you want full control, use `MediaRecorder`, either directly in your own code or via some third-party library.

Comment: I also verified this issue exists only for Google Camera App whose Version is greater than "2.5.052(2005148-30)".

Currently, on Play store, Google Camera App version is "3.2.045(2821762-30)" by using this version you can easily reproduce this issue. Previously Google Camera EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT was working on the V2.5.052.

Comment: It looks like no camera app is supporting it anymore unfortunately